# Adding and updating tests within Azure DevOps Pipeline programmatically using API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc, appveyor

I'm converting one of our projects to use Azure DevOps rather than AppVeyor for CI. As part of the build we use a custom test runner to perform certain tests.

When running in AppVeyor we call the REST API directly from the test runner to inform the build server of the tests being run and to update their status. This is quite straightforward, as shown in the REST sections of their [Add Tests](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-worker-api/#add-tests) and [Update Tests](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-worker-api/#update-tests) documentation, and gives us great integration into AppVeyor's UI.

I've been researching how to do the same in Azure DevOps. I've found a section of the REST API for [adding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) test results. It isn't entirely clear from the API documentation if this is what I would use during a running pipeline, or if this is for some other scenario. I've searched for others trying to do the same thing, but without any luck so far. Most examples talk about uploading a test results file, but this seems a rather indirect way of getting the test results published, especially as I would like to register all the tests before they are run and then update their status as they are completed.

Does anyone have any pointers or examples around publishing test results using the Azure DevOps API during a build?

---

**Solution in detail:**

With Merlin Liang's answer for guidance I've now got this working.

**Step 1.** First I created a new Test Run, which I did at the end of my build job (called `Build`) using a powershell script:

```
  - powershell: |
      $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0"
      $body = @{
          "name" = "IntegrationTests"
          "build" = @{
              "id" = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
          }
          "isAutomated" = $TRUE
          "state" = "InProgress"
      }
      $json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{
          Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
      }
      $runId = $result.id
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID;isOutput=true]$runId"
    displayName: 'Create test run'
    name: CreateTestRun
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Note you have to explicitly give the script access to the `System.AccessToken` in the `env` section, as that variable isn't put into an environment variable by default. The test run state should be `InProgress` to make sure the tests show in the build's test list while they are running.

**Step 2.** Next my pipeline fans out into parallel jobs to run the tests, which need access to the `INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID` variable I created above, so I import that into the job:

```
  - job: IntegrationTests
    dependsOn: Build
    variables:
      INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['CreateTestRun.INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID'] ]
    strategy:
      parallel: 2
    ...
```

My test runner (written in C#) can then construct the URL for `POST`ing and `PATCH`ing tests:

```
$"{this.apiUrl}{this.projectName}/_apis/test/runs/{this.testRunId}/results?api-version=5.0"
```

And adding test attachments:

```
$"{this.apiUrl}{this.projectName}/_apis/test/runs/{this.testRunId}/results/{testResultId}/attachments?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
```

Where those class member variables are just read from the usual environment variables, and `testResultId` is the ID returned by the API when I initially `POST` the test.

Again, I'm explicitly setting the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` in an `env` section when I call the test runner from the Azure Pipeline YAML, and using it in the authorization header.

**Step 3.** Finally I fan-in again mark the test run as complete in a dedicated job which depends on the integration test jobs and must always run even if tests fail:

```
  - job: EndIntegrationTests
    dependsOn:
      - Build
      - IntegrationTests
    condition: always()
    variables:
      INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['CreateTestRun.INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID'] ]
    steps:
    - checkout: none

    - powershell: |
        $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/test/runs/$($env:INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID)?api-version=5.0"
        Write-Host "URL: $url"
        $body = @{
            "state" = "Completed"
        }
        $json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Patch' -Uri $url -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
        }
      displayName: 'Complete test run'
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Note that this job needs to explicitly depend on `Build` so that I can read the output variable `INTEGRATION_TEST_RUN_ID`, and it obviously depends on `IntegrationTests` so that it won't complete the test run until all the tests are finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the answer. Please see this doc: [Surface test results in the Tests tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#surface-test-results-in-the-tests-tab).

Except uploading test results via tasks, such as Publish Test Results task, VS test or etc. We also provide a way to upload the results via [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/Results?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-5.0):

[image]

To achieve what you want, you must create a test run first with one known build number, then post test results to that.

1. [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildreference) a new test to existing build, **specify the `buildID`** in request body.

Sample:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0

{
 "name": "NewTest", 
 "build": { "id": "162" }, 
 "isAutomated": true, 
 "state": "Waiting" 
}
```

2. Run test, so that the test result could become available.
3. Now, post this new test result into the test which created previously.

[
 { "testCaseTitle": "ReferBuild",
   "automatedTestName": "ReferBuildAuto",
   "priority": 1, 
   "outcome": "Passed" 
}]

Here you could refer to the example which showed in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#examples).

4. At last, you can use [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) api.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with what I ended up doing in detail based on your answer. There is a final paragraph at the end about how to get tests to appear in the test list for the build while the test run is still in progress.. if you have any tips about that they would be gratefully received. Otherwise I'll do more digging and perhaps ask a separate question.

Comment: @JamesThurley Display the test details in the build summary tab while the test is in progress, right?

Comment: Hi Merlin, yes that's right. Actually I figured it out: If I set the test run state to "InProgress" instead of "Waiting" then the list of tests appears and shows the tests progressing exactly as I wanted :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JamesThurley Welcome. Glad to hear you achieve the completed process successfully now.